# Add J# to VS.Net 2008

Tags: visual-studio, j#

Can I add J# to the VS.Net 2008 IDE... I've got some old J# code to maintain (just until we port it over to C#).

Comment: Hi,

According to MS, it's not supported in VS 2008 as it was deprecated in Jan 2007, so missed the VS 2008 by several months, due to the Sun settlement.  

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7xsxf8e2.aspx

You can download the J# redists from here. 

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vjsharp/bb188598.aspx

Bob.

Comment: VS 2005 will obviously support it.
Bob.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is the official documentation on it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7xsxf8e2(VS.90).aspx)

```
Note:
Visual J# has been removed from Visual Studio 2008.
```

Your best bet would be to stick to 2005, do your porting in that, then migrate once its complete.